# The header 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' is missing in the response

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, websocket

I am in the middle of creating a client-server application, that allows push notifications through websockets, and followed this guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977020(v=vs.110).aspx.

It is working perfectly localhost, but when I publish the service to Azure, on a site where websockets is allowed, we get this exception: 
*An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: websocket error* 
and the inner exception:
*Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: A WebSocket error occurred. ---> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException: WebSocket upgrade request failed. The header 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' is missing in the response.*

I guess I need to set that 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' somewhere?
I tried changeing the clients endpoint to "wss://" instead of "ws://", but then it tells me that "http is expected".

Comment: Are you sure the request is hitting the right endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying to Azure websites? If so, have you enabled WebSockets on the management portal as the http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/ article covers in the beginning?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. They are already enabled. If not, I get an error, which in brief, is telling me that they are not enabled.

Answer (score -1):

The way to workaround this is to not have websocket sub-protocol specified both at the client and server side.

Comment: Could you elaborate? why and how is this going to help